# Adding a SharePoint feature with multiple class files

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, eventreceiver

I am in the process of making a feature that consists of multiple items.

Currently it contains a Feature.xml file with 4 `ElementManifest` entries; two for a specific contenttype (`Field` definitions and `FieldRef`s), one for some webparts and the last is for a custom pagelayout. All of that is working fine.

I have altered the file with the contenttype (`FieldRef`s) to add a Receiver, since I wish to process whenever an item is added through the `ItemAdding` feature receiver. That part of the file looks as follows (I have removed the assembly and class names, but they are correct):

```
<XmlDocuments>
  <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
    <Receivers>
      <Receiver>
        <Name>NewsAlerts</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
        <Assembly>#AssemblyInfo#</Assembly>
        <Class>#NamespaceToClassFile#</Class>
        <Data></Data>
        <Filter></Filter>
      </Receiver>
    </Receivers>
  </XmlDocument>
</XmlDocuments>
```

Besides this file, I use a custom class file to add some functionality. For both the FeatureReceiver class and the custom class file, do I need to add anything to feature.xml or some of the other xml files to make sure they are included? I want it all added together as ONE feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your feature receiver assembly and the other one should be in the GAC. You can create a SharePoint solution that deploys your feature and puts the assemblies in the GAC so that they are available when the solution is installed.